Error Trying to Search Range for String Match
I'm trying to find a string within a range using the code below, but I get an error: "Object variable or With block variable not set." It looks straightforward so I but I can't find my error.
 Sub FindSomethingInRange()

     Dim sSearchFor as String
     Dim rSearchRange as Range

     sSearchFor = Worksheets("MatchupCalc").Range("E" & i2).Value
     Set rSearchRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Ladder").Range("AP38:AX38")

     Debug.Print FindValueInCellRange(rSearchRange, sSearchFor)

 End Sub

 Function FindValueInCellRange(MyRange As Range, MyValue As Variant) As String
 '---> PURPOSE: Returns address of first cell in range where the value is found.
 
     With MyRange
        FindValueInCellRange = .Find(What:=MyValue, After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), 
        LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, 
        SearchDirection:=xlNext).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
     End With
 
End Function


What is i2 in .Range("E" & i2).Value ?

If you want to split a command across multiple rows, you need to include an _ at the end (e.g. After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _) — the opposite, combining multiple commands into a single line, requires an : (e.g. Dim sFoo AS String: sFoo = "|")

What did you mean by After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count)?  ALso, you should check what happens if nothing is found.
Function FindValueInCellRange(MyRange As Range, MyValue As Variant) As String
    '---> PURPOSE: Returns address of first cell in range where the value is found.
    
    Dim FoundCell As Range
    
    With MyRange
        Set FoundCell = .Find(What:=MyValue, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                              LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
        ' Check if the value was found
        If Not FoundCell Is Nothing Then
            FindValueInCellRange = FoundCell.Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
        Else
            FindValueInCellRange = "Not Found"
        End If
    End With
End Function


After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count) combined with the default SearchDirection:=xlNext ensures that when there are multiple occurrences of the What and you need the first, and the first is in .Cells(1), that one is found ('chosen'), not the next one. Omitting the After parameter sets its argument to the default .Cells(1). The After argument (cell) is always 'checked' last (whether xlNext or xlPrevious).

@VBasic2008, good point. "The cell after which you want the search to begin. This corresponds to the position of the active cell when a search is done from the user interface.
Notice that After must be a single cell in the range. Remember that the search begins after this cell; the specified cell isn't searched until the method wraps back around to this cell."

Find Value in a Single Row

If successful, the result of the Find method is always a reference to a single cell. Therefore, always assign the result to a Range variable and check if the variable contains a reference (check it against Nothing) before using any properties or methods of it.


Sub FindInSingleRowRange()

    ' Reference the workbook.
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets("Ladder")
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range("AP38:AX38")
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets("MatchupCalc")
    Dim dLastRow As Long:
    dLastRow = dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim cell As Range, Value As Variant, i As Long
    
    For i = 2 To dLastRow ' not sure about 2
        Value = dws.Cells(i, "E").Value
        Set cell = RefMatchingCellInRow(srg, Value)
        If cell Is Nothing Then
            Debug.Print """" & CStr(Value) & """ not found in ""'" & sws.Name _
                & "'!" & srg.Address(0, 0) & """!"
        Else
            Debug.Print """" & CStr(Value) & """ found in ""'" & sws.Name _
                & "'!" & cell.Address(0, 0) & """!"
        End If
    Next i
    
End Sub

Function RefMatchingCellInRow( _
    ByVal sourceSingleRowRange As Range, _
    ByVal Value As Variant) _
As Range
    With sourceSingleRowRange
        Set RefMatchingCellInRow = .Find(What:=Value, _
            After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    End With
End Function

Result
"Val7" found in "'Ladder'!AV38"!
"Val15" not found in "'Ladder'!AP38:AX38"!
"Val3" found in "'Ladder'!AR38"!
"Val12" not found in "'Ladder'!AP38:AX38"!
"Val2" found in "'Ladder'!AQ38"!
"Val7" found in "'Ladder'!AV38"!
"Val10" not found in "'Ladder'!AP38:AX38"!
"Val1" found in "'Ladder'!AP38"!
"Val14" not found in "'Ladder'!AP38:AX38"!
"Val4" found in "'Ladder'!AS38"!
xlFormulas vs xlValues

If the source range contains values, xlFormulas will find even if the cells (rows or columns) are hidden while xlValues will not.
If the source range contains formulas, you cannot use xlFormulas while xlValues will still fail to find when cells are hidden.
Both will fail if the source worksheet is filtered.



In this case using xlFormulas will yield the same result while xlValues will not find Val3 and Val7:

"Val7" not found in "'Ladder'!AP38:AX38"!
"Val3" not found in "'Ladder'!AP38:AX38"!
"Val7" not found in "'Ladder'!AP38:AX38"!

On the other hand, this might have been your intention.

